# c: remove two characters from string

Tags: c

I'm working on the string: `{()}` my code searches for the first `)` and replaces it and the character before it `(` with whitespace and the result is `{  }`

What i want to do instead of replacing the match to whitespaces is to remove the parentheses from the string and recursively check the string again using my existing code. I'm trying to find a way to collapse the remaining characters using `memmove` or something similar

```
char openKey[] = "({<[";
char closeKey[] = ")}>]";
pch = strpbrk(parenthesesStack, closeKey);
while (pch != NULL)
{

    if (opposits(*(pch-1),*pch)){
        printf("%c %c\n" , *(pch-1), *pch);
        memmove(pch-1,"  ",2);
    }
    pch = strpbrk (parenthesesStack,closeKey);
}
```

Comment: Just to be sure: You are aware that `memmove`ing the string makes this a quadratic operation, and you can check the well-formedness in linear time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want to move the rest of the string 2 positions to the left?

Try this:

```
    memmove(pch-1, pch+1, strlen(pch+1) + 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `memmove()` and `strlen()`, just use `strcpy()`.

```
strcpy( pch - 1, pch + 1);
```

Comment: `strcpy` might not be a good choice as the source and target strings overlap.

Comment: The only way that `strcpy()` is going to copy the string is by moving from the start to the end of the string, reading from the source and writing to the destination, until it hits a null.  But technically you are correct -- according to the spec the behavior is undefined when source and destination overlap, so `memmove()` is safer to use.